# repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest failed

Tags: android, android-kernel

I want to get the android kernel code, I follow https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels, and mkdir kernel_aosp, my phone is pixel,so I use the

`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b android-msm-marlin-3.18-pie-qpr2`

but it failed, the error is

> fatal: manifest 'default.xml' not available
>
> fatal: manifest default.xml not found

please help me, thank you